# when putting multiple sql commands showing error :There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Friends, when I write these code in asp.net I get an error like this:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first

help me please

```
SqlConnection con = obj.getcon();
con.Open();

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select student_id from student_details", con);
       SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while (dr.Read())
       {
           String ss=dr[0].ToString();
           if (val == ss)
           {



               SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert student_vs_testsession_details(student_id,testsession_id,testsession_status) values('" + val + "','" + Test + "','')", con);
               int val1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


           }
           else
           {


               string message = "<script language=JavaScript> alert('StudentID does not exists!'); </script>";
               if (!Page.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript"))
               {
                   Page.RegisterStartupScript("clientScript", message);
               }
           }

       } 
     dr.Close();
      // con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Do *NOT* do inline parameters in your SQL Statements! It's the fastest way to have problems with injection attacks (no, escaping the input is not sufficient) - take a look at how to use parameterized queries.

Comment: thankyou.. but after parametrized i have the same error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to change your connection string and add this option

```
 "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

Starting from SQL Server 2005 there is MARS option.
With MARS a single **opened** connection could serve more than one command at a time.
So, for example, your connection string should be like this

```
"Server=myServerAddress;" + 
"Database=myDataBase;" + 
"Trusted_Connection=True;" +
"MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
```

[See the docs on MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx)

In a *'normal'* configuration, when a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) is open, the SqlConnection is busy serving the reader and cannot accept other commands.
(See remarks on the link to SqlDataReader).

Your code above has a reader open when you try to issue a command using the same connection.
There are workarounds like filling a DataSet and then looping over it (but for large sets this will impact performances), so the SQL Team at Microsoft introduced MARS

Comment: but that connection string works properly for another sql commands

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not use nested sql, which slows down application performance, but use SQL massive insert. So you could change your code to:

```
SqlConnection con = obj.getcon();

con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into student_vs_testsession_details(student_id,testsession_id,testsession_status) select student_id, " + "'Test','' from student_details where student_id = '" + val + "'", con);
int val1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select student_id from student_details where student_id != " + val , con);

       SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while (dr.Read())
       {
           String ss=dr[0].ToString();

               string message = "<script language=JavaScript> alert('StudentID does not exists!'); </script>";
               if (!Page.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript"))
               {
                   Page.RegisterStartupScript("clientScript", message);
               }

       } 

dr.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not execute multiple command statements for the same connection while the datareader is on... use instead SqlDataAdapter.. Using dataadapter and DataSet will make your work more easy..

Comment: This is incorrect, using `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` in the connection string allows this.